# Removing characters from string in Eval

Tags: asp.net, string, eval

I'm trying to remove the last 2 characters of the string in my .NET code which uses Eval to get the string name. This code isn't right, but it's the idea of what I am trying to do.

.Net code where my DataKeyName = test:

```
 NavigateUrl ='<%#"~/example.aspx?test=" + ((string)Eval("test")).Remove(Eval("test").length -2)) %>'
```

That's clearly wrong, but hopefully conveys what I'm trying to do. So if test = hello!!, I want my navigateURL to be /example.aspx?test=hello (the last 2 characters, !! in this case, is removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a function in codebehind `getNewString(object str)`

```
public object getNewString(object str)
        {
            string mainString = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (str != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str.ToString()))
                {
                    if (str.ToString().Length >= 2)
                    {
                        mainString = str.ToString().Substring(0, str.ToString().Length - 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mainString = str.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
            }
            return mainString;
        }
```

and call that function like this

```
NavigateUrl ='<%# getNewString(Eval("test")) %>'
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the other answer would've worked too but this makes it less cluttered in the .Net code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NavigateUrl ='<%#"~/example.aspx?test=" + Eval("test").ToString().Substring(0, Eval("test").ToString().Length - 2) %>'
```